# Return a string to a custom object type

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, rest

I am trying to write a C# restful web service which returns the customer name when account number is passed as a parameter.

*I have a customer class:*

```
public class Customer_T
{
    public string CustName { get; set; }
}
```

*An interface class:*

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "", Name = "CustomerInfoService")]
public interface CustomerInfo_I
{
    [OperationContract]
    Customer_T CustName(string accountno);
}
```

*Another class called CustomerInfo which implements the CustomerInfo_I interface:*

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class CustomerInfo : CustomerInfo_I
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "customer/{accountno}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Customer_T CustName(string accountno)
    {
        string custName = "";
        CustNameByAccountNo custdb = new CustNameByAccountNo();
        custName = custdb.getCustName(accountno).ToString();
        if (custName.Equals("") == false)
        {
            return new Customer_T { CustName = custName };
        }
        else
        {
            return null; //This is where I want to change
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of returning null, **I would like to return a string "InvalidAccNo"**.
I did try it, but it gave me an error.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'CustomerInfo.Service.Customer_T'
```

Comment: Why are you returning Customer_T is you want to return a string?

Comment: Customer_T has the CustName property defined in that class. i want to display the string "InvalidCustAcc" if no customer name was returned. i don't want the string to be assigned to the CustName property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to return a string since your return type is defined as a `Customer_T`. One option you might want to consider is to take a look at fault handling inside of WCF to return a fault to a user rather than repurposing a single object. Throwing the fault can be used in indicate that an invalid account number was specified.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "", Name = "CustomerInfoService")]
public interface CustomerInfo_I
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(string))]
    Customer_T CustName(string accountno);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx

Also, your Customer class, you should mark the class with the `DataContract` attribute and your data members with `DataMember` in order to return complex types.

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer_T
{
    [DataMember]
    public string CustName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
    if (custName.Equals("") == false)
    {
        return new Customer_T { CustName = custName };
    }
    else
    {
        return new Customer_T { CustName = "Invalid Customer Name!" };
    }
```

Although it sounds like you might want a property in Customer_T of IsValid, or something like that. Set it to false in the 2nd case, and override ToString of Customer_T:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.IsValid ? this.CusName : "Invalid Customer Name!";
}
```

Then you can do:

```
    if (custName.Equals("") == false)
    {
        return new Customer_T { CustName = custName };
    }
    else
    {
        return new Customer_T { IsValid = false };
    }
```

Just make sure you're setting IsValid to true in the Customer_T constructor, so it is valid by default.

Comment: this is working better than before. rather than returning null, it is now returning null to the CustName property.  what i am trying to do is to show a string "InvalidCustAcc" and not display the CustName property. i hope i am being clear here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The method is declared to return a `Customer_T`, which your string is not an instance of. I would advise against it but if you really want to make a method that results an instance of an object OR a string, you could have it return `object`. Which both `Customer_T` and `string` are.

Change

```
public Customer_T CustName(string accountno)
```

Into:

```
public object CustName(string accountno)
```

The problem with this is that now the caller of the method doesn't know for sure what it will result in.

Comment: just tried this.. changing the type *Customer_T* to *object* didn't work.  its now giving me a **HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**

Comment: probably the consumer of your webservice is expecting to find a method that results in a `Customer_T` and such method does no longer exist now.

Comment: so is there any possible way to do what is required here?

Comment: What request did you send to the webservice? If you request for an object of type `Customer_T` the web service will find no suitable method to execute. You need to ask for an object of type `object`, and then cast it to a `Customer_T` if it isn't a string.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right. 
In your Interface, you have declared that CustName returns a Customer_T, but now you have changed your mind and need a string as return value.
That's not good from a webservice contract standpoint.

So if you need the Customer_T as return value don't change anything and throw an exception if the custname is not found. Alternatives are

- Add a new method with the appropriate signature
- Change (Breaking change) your contract in a way that CustName returns
  a string.